# Pipeline and GridSearchCV with a custom regression function - passing parameters?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to use Pipeline and GridSearchCV with a custom regression function.

I've got the approach to work using sklearn.svm.SVR by setting up its class, and then passing the parameters from the dictionary when setting up GridSearchCV.

I don't seem to be able to do the same thing when using my own regression function (RegFn). In particular I want to pass the values from the parameter dictionary to the RegFn when setting it up.

Grateful for any pointers on how to get this working.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler 
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline   
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator,RegressorMixin                                                  


parameters = dict(regfn__i=i, regfn__j=j, regfn__k=k)  
regfn = RegFn(numInputs=noinputs, numOutputs=1, i = 100, j = 1, k =0.5)
scaler = StandardScaler()   

steps = [ ('scaler', scaler), ('regfn', regfn   ) ]  

grid = GridSearchCV(Pipeline(steps), param_grid=parameters, cv=splits, refit=True, verbose=3, n_jobs=1)
```

**Updated class structure**

```
class RBF(BaseEstimator,RegressorMixin):

    def __init__(self, i,j,k,numInputs=10,numOutputs=1):
        self.numInputs = numInputs
        self.numOutputs = numOutputs
        self.i = i
        self.j = j
        self.k = k
        .....

    def fit(self, x, y):
      ....

    def predict(self, x):
      ....
```

*I'm still not able to pass the i, j, k values from the dictionary. Am I referring to them in the correct way?*

Comment: Did you inherit `RegFn` from `BaseEstimator`?

Comment: You need to change your parameters from `RegFn__i` to `regfn__i`. They should be same name which is passed to pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a custom estimator - [it should be inherited from sklearn.base.BaseEstimator](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/developers/contributing.html#rolling-your-own-estimator) and it should implement methods `fit()` and `predict()`.

If you want to be able to pass parameters to your estimator you should also implement `__init__()` method.

[Example from sklearn docs](http://scikit-learn.org/dev/developers/contributing.html#rolling-your-own-estimator):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin
>>> from sklearn.utils.validation import check_X_y, check_array, check_is_fitted
>>> from sklearn.utils.multiclass import unique_labels
>>> from sklearn.metrics import euclidean_distances
>>> class TemplateClassifier(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
...
...     def __init__(self, demo_param='demo'):
...         self.demo_param = demo_param
...
...     def fit(self, X, y):
...
...         # Check that X and y have correct shape
...         X, y = check_X_y(X, y)
...         # Store the classes seen during fit
...         self.classes_ = unique_labels(y)
...
...         self.X_ = X
...         self.y_ = y
...         # Return the classifier
...         return self
...
...     def predict(self, X):
...
...         # Check is fit had been called
...         check_is_fitted(self, ['X_', 'y_'])
...
...         # Input validation
...         X = check_array(X)
...
...         closest = np.argmin(euclidean_distances(X, self.X_), axis=1)
...         return self.y_[closest]
```

PS please be aware that the example above shows how to create a custom classifier, so it might contain a code, which is not quite appropriate for regressors

Comment: It would be better to replace ClassifierMixin with RegressorMixin in this case. :)

Comment: It would also not make any sense to have `self.classes_ = unique_labels(y)` for regression case. But I think OP will get the point.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this, but am not able to pass the values through correctly. I can't work out how I should be referring to them. I've updated the message.

Comment: @tmn103, are you getting any error message or a warning? And what are you passing as `i`, `j`, `k` in `dict(regfn__i=i, regfn__j=j, regfn__k=k)` - I hope you're passing lists there?

Comment: @MaxU - I'm getting "TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'i', 'j', and 'k'. I was passing i, j, k as numpy arrays (using np.linspace), but just tried with lists and get the same error.

Comment: @tmn103, can you provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we could reproduce your issue?

Comment: @tmn103, i think the easiest way would be to specify default values in the `__init__()` method. Example: `def __init__(self, i=0,j=0,k=0,numInputs=10,numOutputs=1):`

Comment: @tmn103 You should always use default initial values for custom scikit estimators [as mentioned here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#instantiation)